# Workaround for Import not supporting the \leqslant TeX macro

Tags: import, latex, undocumented

```
$\{A\leqslant x\leqslant B\}$
```

Copy the code into Notebook, and you'll lose the `less sign`, this can be rendered well in Mathematica.StackExchange

$\{A\leqslant x\leqslant B\}$

---

And you can also `ImportString["$\{A\\leqslant x\\leqslant B\\}$","TeX"]//CreateDocument`,

Here is the problem, the `leqslant` was removed, are there any options of `ImportString` or are there any other methods to Import some latex codes without losing some information?

Comment: It seems you need something like the `"ConversionRules"` option but in the opposite direction, as that appears to be only for conversion *into* LaTex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no (documented) options of `ImportString` directly.

But who cares? Just get rid of leqslant, e.g., like this:

```
ImportString["$\{A\\leqslant x\\leqslant B\\}$" /.
  s_ String :> StringReplace[s,"leqslant" -> "leq"], "TeX"] // CreateDocument
```

Comment: yes, this is one way, the bad thing, I should build one replace rules, I'll use it if no better methods.

Answer (score 4):

This is longer than a comment, but does not provide a solution (obviously, Rolf's answer does the job perfectly).

Spelunking in `ImportString` reveals that it uses the same options as `Import`. `Import` on the other hand uses a set of private functions, one for each import format, with different option-sets. We are interested in $TeX$ import options. Ultimately, in the definition of `` System`Convert`TeXImportDump`validateInput ``, the following options are listed:

```
{
"InstallDir" :> System`Convert`TeXImportDump`$TeX2NBDir,
"OutputFile" -> None,
"InputPath" -> {},
"TeXCommand" -> "\\input amsmath.tns %\n",
"Verbose" -> False,
"StyleDefinitions" -> Null,
"MathLink" -> True,
"FEKernel" -> True,
"MathCommand" -> "math",
"MathLinkDebug" -> False,
"NotebookDebug" -> False,
"FullDebug" -> False,
"LogFile" -> Null,
"BaseFormat" -> Null,
"Flush" -> False,
"CoreDump" -> False,
"Raw" -> False,
"Normalize" -> True
}
```

General options are:

```
{
Path :> $Path,
"DoNotDecode",
ConversionOptions,(* Obsolete after v6.0 *)
"Channel",
CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"
};
```

Using `ImportString[..., "Verbose" -> True]` reveals that we are indeed using the `amsmath.tns` file, that is the Wolfram interface for `amsmath.sty`. It's quite easy to figure out that `\leqslant` is defined in the `amssymb.sty` and `amssymb.tns` files (the `.tns` files can be found at `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "\\SystemFiles\\IncludeFiles\\TeX\\Import"}`, the same location the `"InstallDir"` option uses as a default). I'm not a $TeX$ expert, so I've tried simply to include more packages with `\include` in the `"TeXCommand"` option, perhaps this is not the way to go (though `"Verbose" -> True` indicates that both packages are parsed):

```
CellPrint@First@First@
   ImportString["$\\{A\\leqslant x\\leqslant B\\}$", "TeX", (* "Verbose" -> True, *)
    "TeXCommand" -> "\\input amsmath.tns \\input amssymb.tns %\n"]
```

[image]

indicating that the symbols are there, but are displayed incorrectly. I've tried different encodings (found under `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "\\SystemFiles\\CharacterEncodings"}`), with no avail. According to `amssymb.tns`, the unicode character code for `\leqslant` is **unicode 2270** (it also means that *Mathematica* in theory does support `\leqslant`).

One might want to play with `CharacterEncoding`, or with the `"InstallDir"` option (by pointing to a non-WRI $TeX$ installation) or with the `"StyleDefinitions"` option. If you have more experience with $TeX$ than me, please feel free to improve this post!